# SSIS package that used to work fine started failing for below reason.Any Ideas?

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I have an SSIS Packgae that copies data between SQL server Database and an Access database. It have been working fine and today I started to have below error and can't find a solution for it.

> [OLE DB Destination [84]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Cannot open database ''. 
>    It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.".
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. 
>    The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (84) 
>   failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" 
>   (97). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. 
>   The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>
> [OLE DB Source [139]] Error: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC02020C4. 
>    The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component,
>    but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Comment: have you checked the access db? is it not corrupted?

Comment: its not corrupted because i have backups of the file and since i thought it was corrupted i replaced it with a new copy.

Comment: i got thi sto work when i change the destination from local server to a file path and when i debug it worked and copied the data.I set it to run under 32 bit and all that.Now i deployed it to the SQL server and when i fire the job that kicks the SSIS package it started to throw this error which i think has something to do with 32/64bit run time. i dont know where to fix it with in sql server at this point.Any ideas?

Comment: error is Data Flow Task:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SL_Obligations_Detail" failed with error code 0xC0209303.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Comment: If you're sure about 32/64 bit, then go to sql server agent job - right click 'properties' - go to steps - double click - go to configuration tab opened - select advanced tab - checkmark 32-bit runtime.